# Upper bound for the Green's function of the Laplacian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, upper-lower-bounds

Let $M^n$ be a compact Riemannian manifold without boundary. Then the Green's function for the Laplacian, $G(p,q),$ satisfies $$G(p,q)\leq A \; d(p,q)^{2-n}$$ where $d(p,q)$ is the distance between the points $p,q\in M.$  We can assume that $\int_M G(p,y) dy=0.$

How can we estimate the constant $A$? Are there any simple examples, like real or complex projective spaces, where it is possible to estimate $A$?

Any suggestions or references would be extremely helpful.

Comment: In the limiting case $q\to p$  this is called the Robin constant. The book [Robin Functions for Complex Manifolds and Applications](https://books.google.com/books?id=pz_VAwAAQBAJ) looks like a good place to start.

Comment: @Michelle Thank you Michelle - I have looked at the notes you suggested, but I still don't understand  how to estimate this constant. Is there any (more specific) direction you could give me?